# Reusing Tensorflow Variables

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to have basically two different graphs based on whether I am training my network or actually running it. Basically, one piece uses some unsupervised techniques to learn the values of a given matrix and then I want to use the exact same matrix in a different graph.

I know how to get the value of the matrix using `matrix_value = sess.run(my_matrix, {input=input_data})` but then is there a way to initialize a `tf.Variable` with a set value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

value = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
init = tf.constant_initializer(value)

with tf.Session():
    x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=[2, 4], initializer=init)
    x.initializer.run()
    print(x.eval())
```

I hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create two identical graphs, you could just use the same but run different nodes.

Let me explain what I mean. Let's look at this example:

```
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1], stddev=0.1))
# Declare bias variable initialized to a constant 0.1
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[1]))

y_pred = x_ph * W + b

# loss function
loss = tf.mul(tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(tf.sub(y_pred, y_ph))), 1. / 2)
```

The first part calls the `train_op`.

```
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)
```

This op will run a gradient descent step based on the `loss` op which will induce an update of the variables `W` and `b`.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # initialize all the variables by running the initializer operator
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in xrange(num_epoch):
        # Run sequentially the train_op and loss operators with
        # x_ph and y_ph placeholders fed by variables x and y
        _, loss_val = sess.run([train_op, loss], feed_dict={x_ph: x, y_ph: y})
        print('epoch %d: loss is %.4f' % (epoch, loss_val))
```

But now if you just want to run it you can just run the `y_pred` op. It will pick up the current values of `W` and `b` and they won't be modified as you didn't call the `train_op`.

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # see what model do in the test set
    # by evaluating the y_pred operator using the x_test data
    test_val = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={x_ph: x_test})
```

When you ask TensorFlow to run an op `y_pred` with new data `x_test` fed into `x_ph`, it will only compute `y_pred = x_ph * W + b` (taking `W` and `b` as constant) without modifying anything else.

Also, it is worth mentioning that when you're done with training you have the ability to override some variable values (e.g. in the case of a variable value learnt to be very close to 1, you could just set it to 1 directly as per the [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started).

> We could improve this manually by reassigning the values of W and b to the perfect values of -1 and 1. A variable is initialized to the value provided to tf.Variable but can be changed using operations like tf.assign. For example, W=-1 and b=1 are the optimal parameters for our model. We can change W and b accordingly:

```
fixW = tf.assign(W, [-1., 1.])
fixb = tf.assign(b, [1.])
sess.run([fixW, fixb])
print(sess.run(loss, {x_ph:x_test}))
```

Comment: They are not identical graphs. The training process requires an entirely different graph (not isomorphic) to the actual graph I will use for real time classification.

Comment: I see, if they don't share any sub parts in common then obviously you can't reuse those. :)